# How to generate PayPal donate button for custom email address?

Tags: paypal

How to generate a PayPal donate button for custom email address?

Answer (score 0):

For an unhosted button, use a link like: `https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_donations&item_name=Donation%20purpose%20goes%20here&amount=&currency_code=USD&business=emailusernam@somedomain.com`

Use an image such as https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif

---

For the options available via https://www.paypal.com/buttons , you must create and save the button when logged into the receiving PayPal account, resulting in a hosted button.

Comment: You can add a `return` variable, documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/#paypal-checkout-page-variables -- however, there is never any guarantee someone will return after donating. For guest checkouts PayPal may be obligated by credit card companies to show them a receipt with a click to return, and for logged-in users there may be a timer before the redirect, and that tab may simply be closed or their browser crash, etc.